# Razor Pages Entity Framework Database Context Can't Do Commands

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am trying to add a Entity Framework Context to my Razor Pages ASP.Net Core program using two different guides:

https://ef.readthedocs.io/en/staging/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-student-pages

I have gone through both of these and yet when i try and access the context, the same thing happens:

The only thing that comes up is the 'equals' method

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RQ6r.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: use `new PHDTestWorkScreenContext()`

Answer (score 0):

> The only thing that comes up is the 'Equals' method

By using class directly, you just have accessibility to `static` members of `PHDTestWorkScreenContext` and you didn't even see the `non-static` members.

As `Frahad Zamani` in a comment saying you, you must create a new instance of this class to work with its members. follow the below code:

```
   public void OnGet()
   {
      var phdTestWorkScreenContext = new PHDTestWorkScreenContext();
      //then
      var test = phdTestWorkScreenContext. ...
   }
```

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

@Hamed Moghadasi is correct.  However, if you are trying to use dependency injection you will need to use it this way.

```
 public class  NewJobModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly PHDTestWorkScreenContext _context;
    public ContactModel(PHDTestWorkScreenContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public void OnGet()
    {

        var test = _context...
   }
}

//make sure to update your startup cs so you can use DI
services.AddRazorPages();

    services.AddDbContext<PHDTestWorkScreenContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Your Connection String Namefrom the config file")));
```